# NameError: name 'first' is not defined

Tags: python, spyder, nameerror

I am new to python and I am trying to get plot of a function.
This is my code:

```
class Optic():
    def __init__(self):
        '''
        param define
        '''
        global time,lamda, light_speed, Fc, D, z, beta, T0
        self.__time = np.linspace(-400,400, 1600) #Picosec
        self.__lamda = 1550000 #Picometer
        self.__light_speed = 0.3 #meter/Picosec
        self.__Fc=light_speed/lamda #Hz
        self.__D = 17*np.power(10,-6) #sec/meter
        self.__z=[0,10000,20000,30000] #meter
        self.__beta = (-(np.power(lamda,2)/(2*np.pi*light_speed))*D) #sec/meter
        self.__T0 = 200
#        time = np.linspace(-400*np.power(10,-12), 0.5*np.power(10,-12), 400*np.power(10,-12)) #sec
#        lamda = 1550*np.power(10,-9) #meter
#        light_speed = 3*np.power(10,8) #sec/meter
#        Fc=light_speed/lamda #Hz
#        D = 17*np.power(10,-6) #sec/meter
#        z=[0,10000,20000,30000] #meter
#        beta = (-(np.power(lamda,2)/(2*np.pi*light_speed))*D) #sec/meter
#        T0 = 20*np.power(10,-12)

    def firstPulse(self):
        global first
        first = np.exp(-0.5*np.power(time/T0,2))

def main():
    plt.plot(first, time)
    plt.show()


if (__name__ == "__main__"): 
    main()
```

but I get:

```
NameError: name 'first' is not defined
```

BTW, I am using Spyder.

Comment: Where do you define `plt`?  Did you call `firstPulse()` before you called `main()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have init Optic and call def firstPulse(self) which is defining that variable.

Something like this:

```
def main():
    opt = Optic():
    opt.firstPulse()
    plt.plot(first, time)
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call

```
plt.plot(first, time)
```

you haven't defined first.
You could put

```
first = 0
```

somewhere in your code.
You may then see problems with `time` (and `plt` unless you have the appropriate imports).

It might make more sense to pass `first` in to `Optic`. In fact, all the `global` variables could be sent in to the init function instead.

```
def __init__(self):
```

could become

```
def __init__(self, first):
```

And then you could refer to `self.first` later if you set it up in the init method.

As a general rule, globals are best avoided.